# How to get .jar resources path?

Tags: java, jar, path, resources

I'm using a custom method to get pictures from the `resources/` folder. The hardcoded path works well when programming during production (`src/main/resources/`). However when delivering, I would need to make this path relative to the .jar root. So I made this.

```java
public static Image getImageFromFile(String file)
{
    Image image = null;
    try
    {
        String path = FileUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(file).toExternalForm();
        System.out.println(path);

        File pathToFile = new File(path);
        image = ImageIO.read(pathToFile);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    return image;
}
```

```java
file:/C:/Users/Hugo/Desktop/Hugo/Java%20Workspace/ClashBot/bin/main/icons/level-label.png
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.lycoon.clashbot.utils.FileUtils.getImageFromFile(FileUtils.java:55)
```

The printed path is valid and points to the corresponding picture. However, the program raises an IOException.
Why can't it find the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're jumping through way too many hoops. It's quite simple:

```
FileUtils.class.getResource("path.png");
// -OR-

try (var in = FileUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("path.png")) {
    // in is an inputstream.
}
```

is all you need. Note that this means the `path.png` file is searched for in the exact same place (and even same 'subdir') as where FileUtils lives. So if you have, say, a file on `C:\Projects\Hugo\MyApp\myapp.jar`, and if you were to unzip that, inside you'd find `com/foo/pkg/FileUtils.class`, then the string `path.png` would look in that jar, and for `com/foo/pkg/path.png`. In other words, `AnyClass.class.getResource("AnyClass.class")` will let a class find its own class file. If you want to go from the 'root' of the jar, add a slash, i.e. `FileUtils.class.getResource("/path.png")` looks in the same jar, and for `/path.png` inside that jar.

`getResource` returns a URL. `getResourceAsStream` returns a stream (which you need to close; use try-with-resources as I did). Just about every resource-using API out there will take one of these two as input. For example, ImageIO does so; it even takes a URL so you can use either one:

```
var image = ImageIO.read(FileUtils.class.getResource("imgName + ".png"));
```

Yes. It's a one-liner. This will load images straight from within a jar file!

Comment: My code lacked of that preceding `/` to set from root! Thank you for your complete answer. Upvoted ;)

Comment: Was in a similar situation and needed to retrieve a font from resources for use in a 3rd API. Problem: the API takes as input neither URL nor Inputstream, but instead expects a Path as String. The only solution I found until now is to retrieve the font from resource as inputstream, generate a temp file out of it and pass the path to this file as param to the 3rd API. It works, but the workaround is quite heavy. Is there a more straighforward way of dealing with these situations?

Comment: @JulienBerthoud The answer is straightforward but probably not what you wanted to hear: Don't use crap APIs that demand a path. For what its worth, any APIs that are a light wrapper around calling OS-level functionality always works like this: Windows, itself, can't go diggin' into a jar file.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use a slightly different call like this:

```
java.net.URL fileUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(file);
String filePath = URLDecoder.decode(fileUrl.getPath(), "UTF-8");
image = ImageIO.read(filePath);
```

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() is not neccessarily the right loader. It's also a mouthful. That image is going to be in the exact same place your own class file is, so, ClassYouAreIn.class.getResource is the best way.

Comment: This is needlessly complicated and limiting. Just.. feed the URL that .getResource gives you striaght to ImageIO.read. It can handle URLs, paths, inputstreams, whatever you want.

Comment: My purpose was a pedagogical one. I wanted to provide the reasoning behind the magic of the ImageIO.read overloaded methods. In fact, there is 4 overload for the read method: `read(File input); read(ImageInputStream stream); read(InputStream input); and read(URL input);` when coding, we do not always have that many options, and my answer was to expose the URL class that is less known that the String class for instance. But I aknowledge that `FileUtils.class.getResource` is less "mouthful" than `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader`